# How to Use a Timer in an if statement

Tags: java, timer, int

I need to update the amount of food in my game every x amount of time. I want to use an if statement but it wont work because timers and ints dont work together I guess?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(200, this);
    public void update()
    {
        double dt = 0;
        timer += dt;
        if(timer > 1000)
        {
            food++;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `timer += 0`??  For my money, I would consider calculating the amount of time which has passed since the "last feed" and use that instead, as timers are inherently inaccurate, but that's me.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question I needed but it could be useful for another game that I have in development. So thanks? But I need the Timer to be working with an Int any Idea how this can work?

Comment: As a "general" rule, time based comparisons are better then incrementing a counter as they will take into better account system overheads and potential delays which might occur which can cause a timer to become "irregular", just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using real time in this. You will just need to have 2 variables (the time of last feed and time now) to be able to do this. Just calculate the time difference and place it in your if condition. Refer to the sample below:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static Date lastDate = new Date();
    public static int food = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Food was added on " + lastDate.toString() + ". Food now is " + food);
        while (food < 5) {
            update();
        }
    }

    public static void update() {
        Date dateNow = new Date();
        // in milliseconds
        long diff = dateNow.getTime() - lastDate.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        // long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        // long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        // long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        // If more than 5 seconds have passed
        if (diffSeconds > 5) { // just change this to your desired interval
            lastDate = new Date(); // get the time now
            food++; // increment food
            System.out.println("Food was added on " + lastDate.toString() + ". Food now is " + food);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Food was added on Fri Mar 29 09:15:08 SGT 2019. Food now is 0
Food was added on Fri Mar 29 09:15:14 SGT 2019. Food now is 1
Food was added on Fri Mar 29 09:15:20 SGT 2019. Food now is 2
Food was added on Fri Mar 29 09:15:26 SGT 2019. Food now is 3
Food was added on Fri Mar 29 09:15:32 SGT 2019. Food now is 4
Food was added on Fri Mar 29 09:15:38 SGT 2019. Food now is 5
```

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis If it can help then please don't forget to accept it as an answer and up vote it! :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. It worked beautifully I tweaked it to work with my game and it is running amazingly. One thing the game idles now when this is working. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis You just have to run that code in another thread. Refer to this on how to create threads -> http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html